# How To Calculate a Tangent In Degrees Without a Calculator

Tags: trigonometry, pi

So the other day in my Geometry class, I was bored so I decided to try and calculate pi (which is one of many things I do when I am bored). During that class, I finally developed an equation to calculate pi. I did this by using a polygon with an apothem of a and n sides and I found the perimeter before dividing that by 2 times the apothem in order to estimate pi by using a polygon with a large number of sides to represent a circle.
pi = (2anTan(360/(2n)))/(2a) which I then simplified to pi = nTan(360/(2n))
where the value of n can be set to any value greater than zero. But the higher the value of m is, the more accurate the equation is. I set the n variable on my graphing calculator to 9,999,999,999 and typed in the equation. Sure enough, my calculator outputed 3.141592654. I also figured out that i can calculate pi indefinitely by setting n to an infinite number. For example, I set n to 4 and then do my long multiplication and division, then i add a 4 to the end of my multiplication and division problems and complete another digit of calculations. I can then repeat this process to set n as an infinite value.

But now I want to calculate pi even further. The only problem is, my calculator has a maximum output display of 10 digits. So, how can I calculate a tangent in degrees without a calculator? I have found plenty of infinite equations to calculate a tangent in radians. However, considering that I am only 14 and I haven't exactly learned what a radian is yet, this doesn't help. Can someone please tell me how to calculate a tangent in degrees? Or how to convert radians to degrees (if that's possible, again I don't know what a radian is)? And if necessary what is a radian?

Answer (score 1):

If you take a circular arc of radius $r$ and arc length $l$, then the corresponding angle will be $l/r$ radians.  In particular, a radian is just $180/\pi$ degrees.  This would convert an expression like $\tan(360/2n)$ working with degrees to one like $\tan(\pi/n)$ working with radians.  This is somewhat unfortunate, since you can't very well plug in $\pi$ if that's the value you're trying to calculate.  Note that your method is basically equivalent to saying that the derivative of the tangent function at $x=0$ is equal to one.

My take is that the inverse tangent function provides a reasonable method for approximating $\pi$ by hand.  [Machin's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machin-like_formula) gives the following expansion:

$\begin{eqnarray} \pi & = & 16\arctan(1/5) - 4\arctan(1/239) \\
& = & \left(\frac{4}{5} - \frac{4}{3*5^3} + \frac{4}{5*5^5} - \frac{4}{7*5^3} + \ldots 
\right) + \left(- \frac{4}{239} +  \frac{4}{3*239^3} - \frac{4}{5*239^5} + \frac{4}{7*239^7} - \ldots
\right)
\end{eqnarray}$
The justification that this works requires Taylor series, but computing approximations this way is pure algebra.

The good news is that dividing by $5$ is easy by hand, and the convergence is fairly rapid.  The bad news is that dividing by $239$ by hand is pretty painful.  However, it's not hard at all to get beyond 10 digits.  Historically, this method was used by [William Shanks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Shanks) to correctly compute 527 digits of pi before the existence of computers.